# How to Get MapView Center Latitude and Longitude Every time when Mapview are Swiped in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the Google Map SDk for showing location to a user in my app. In my app I want to center the latitude and longitude to the user every time they swipe/zoom or change the map.

For that I put one center location in my GMSMapView using the following code:

```
- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *)mapView 
 didChangeCameraPosition: (GMSCameraPosition *)position 
 {
double latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude;
double longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude;

// now do something with latitude and longitude
 }
```

But this is not giving me the center location and latitude every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: DId you read google documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#zoom

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on didChangeCameraPosition here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#aabd01d59d7680799a0c24d3c8b5e4622

Says this:

> This may not be called for all intermediate camera positions. It is always called for the final position of an animation or gesture.

Answer (score -1):

Set google map delegate first

mapview.deligate=self;

this will give you centre coordinate

Comment: the question requires the centering of the map, this instruction sets only the delegate

Comment: yaa right
bt after this you have to add

-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
{
    double latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude;
    double longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude;
}